# Stack Navigator not showing screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

My Stack Navigator doesn't show the screen that is rendered beneath it.

This is what my component renders. If I comment the first and last 3 lines, the content is shown as desired.

```
<Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginEmail">
                {() => (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                {CONNECT_TO_APP_TXT}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.inputsWrapper}>
                            <Input
                                label={EMAIL_TXT}
                                placeholder={EMAIL_TXT}
                                isRequired={true}
                                onChangeText={setEmail}
                            />
                            <CustomButton
                                outerStyle={styles.button}
                                label={CONTINUE_TXT}
                                accessibilityLabel={PRESS_CONTINUE_ACC_TXT}
                                onPress={sendRequest}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>{errorMsg}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to return.

```
<Stack.Screen name="LoginEmail">
                {() => return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
```